# How to Retrieve all positions of user from LinkedIn profile

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I am using this array to get all data and positions of user but it will return only the current positions of user not the past positions. And I am using the `r_basicprofile` only.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,formatted-name,phonetic-first-name,phonetic-last-name,formatted-phonetic-name,current-share,num-connections,num-connections-capped,headline,location,industry,summary,picture-url,email-address,public-profile-url,specialties,positions,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request)?format=json
```

Any ideas?